# Why is my border overlapping my JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, border

I am trying to put a border around my JTable for my health tracking program, but the border is overlapping the table:

[image]

```
Border border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED),"Summary");

Object[][] statsObj;
String[] headers = {"","","","","",""}    

JTable statsT = new JTable(statsObj, headers);
statsT.setBackground(null);
statsT.setShowGrid(false);
statsT.setBorder(border);
```

Any idea what is going on or how I can fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix that with wrapping your `JTable` with help of `JScrollPane` or `JPanel` and setting `Border` to that component. For example:

```
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(statsT);
pane.setBorder(border);
```

if you needn't to show table header add `statsT.setTableHeader(null);`

Or with `JPanel`:

```
JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
p.add(statsT);
p.setBorder(border);
```

But, it is better to use `JScrollPane`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that worked well. And thanks for the additional comment on .setTableHeader. I knew there had to be a way to do that, but I hadn't put much time into looking for the proper way yet.